# Two virtual machines with different external IP addresses (VMWare)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, proxy

If I create a Virtual Machine with VMWare it gets a different IP address than the host, but only different in the last number. The external IP address will stay the same, correct? How can I easily assign 2 different external IP addresses for 2 Virtual Machines (with a proxy service) so that both VMs look like completely different users to any website or service?

Comment: You likely cannot. You need to first own the external ip addresses, which is rare and costs money, only then you can look into forwarding ports etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If I create a Virtual Machine, with VMWare

With what? vmware server? vmware player? wmware server? Vmware fusions. Wmware ESX? (hint: the tag vmware is deprecated for a reason).

> it gets a different IP address then the host (but only the last number). 
>   The external IP address will stay the same. (Correct?)

That really depends on how you confgure the network. Both for the VM and for the host OS. You can use virtual networks, NAT or direct access. If you use the direct access to the network if is the same as for a regular computer.

> How can I easily assign 2 different external IP addresses for 2 Virtual Machines (with a proxy service). So that both VM's look like completely different users to any website or service.

Assuming that with external IP addresses does not refer to a host (and VM's) behind a NAT at home and external as 'not at home', then simply
configure as follows:

1. Let the VMs connect directly to the real network.
2. Set different static IPs on the VMs or use DHCP.

Done.

If you means at home, with only one IP public IPv4 address and NAT: You cannot for IPv4.

If at home and with IPv6: same as the first answer. Plenty of IPs to do real routing.

All answers seem a tad generic. For more detailed answers you really need to give more detailed information.  Feel free to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1094998/edit) that into your post.

---

Added after comment:

Current setup (IPs guessed)

```
 Host (w7).
 DHCP req      --------+
 192.168.1.100         |
                       |
 VM1 (w10)             [===========]
 DHCP req      --------[   Router  ]------------------- Internet
 192.168.1.101         [===========]
                       |
 VM2 (w10)             |
 DHCP req      --------+
 192.168.1.102
```

The router would also have two IP addresses:
 one on the left of the drawing (say 192.168.1.1)
 one of the right of the drawing (its public IP, say 1.2.3.4

It is doing an ungly hack called NAT to connect multiple internal hosts to the network without having sufficient public IP v4 addresses.

Now you can forward ports on the router to a host on the inside.
E.g. you can tell that 1.2.3.4:80 should be send to VM1.

But you only have one public external IP and you can only forward one tupel of IP:port. That leaves you with two choices:

1. Forward another port. This will work. Put you will still use the same public IP, so they will not appear to be 'completely different'.
2. Get another public IP. You may be able to pay your ISP to get multiple IP. E.g. 1.2.3.5. Note that this will probably be IP in the same range. That does not fit my diffenition of 'completely different'.

Getting the ISP you configure the router with two different IPs from different ranges on its external side is technically possible, but it is extremely unlikely that the ISP will do this for you.

That leaves two more options:

1. Get a second Internet connection from a different provider.
2. Or find a completely different computer elsewhere on the Internet and tell that PC to forward all traffic to your router.

That would look like this:

```
 Internet ----  Your server elsewhere ---> send to 1.2.3.4:2080
```

And at home you would forward this 1.2.3.4:2080 to VM2.

Comment: I am using VMware player running Windows 7. The host is running Windows 10 Professional x64. For now I use the 'bridged network' option whereby the VM connects to the host's network automatically. As explained, this results in the VM's IP being nearly identical to the host's IP (and any other VM's IP that is running on the same PC), apart from the last 2 digits. I want the VMs to have completely indistinguishable IPs, as far as the outside

Comment: world is concerned. I am not very technical and was therefore wondering how to configure this within VMware, if possible.

Comment: Added more to the post. Still not sure which problem you are trying to solve. Making it seem 'complete;y different' sounds like you have a problem or a goal and are trying to apply one solution, rather than asking 'how do I solve this'. That one solution might work, but it might not be the best.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make your VMs look different to services outside your network.

You can use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) to accomplish this.  You can install TOR on both VMs and request new IPs as necessary.

Comment: That is actually a good idea. Probably damn slow, but a great way to solve what is probably the intended question.

Comment: @Hennes I thought it was a good idea, thats is why I posted the answer :D

Comment: This is a great idea, but I'm afraid it would slow down the connection too much. The VM needs the connection to as fast and smooth as possible to achieve its goal.